# How to fix `pywintypes.com_error` in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, win32com

I'm trying to get this program running.

I uses Python 3.7.2 in Win10 Enterprise (Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763) and the system is based on 64 bit.

I tried to make it work on several PCs. On some of them, it worked.

```
import win32com.client
o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Object.Name")
o.Method()
o.property = "New Value"
print(o.property)
o.prop_map_get_.keys()

o = win32com.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
o.Visible = 1
o.Workbooks.Add()
o.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Hello"
```

*Error :*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Object.Name")
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Ungültige Klassenzeichenfolge', None, None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to disable all the secure-boot-options in the BIOS. I had this problem, too.